# 7-zip doesn't open files with password from windows explorer

Tags: 7-zip

Everything worked fine, then I updated 7-zip and files with password cann't be open. Windows 7.

Files without password open as usual. Everything works if I use 7zFM, browse to file and open it here. It works if I right-click "extract here". But if I just double click to browse it, it prompts password and after entering it it just disappears.

So, everything works except opening files with password from windows explorer to view their content in 7zFM.

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get 7-Zip from a known site, such as [7-Zip.org](https://www.7-zip.org/), and reinstall the software.

Use an appropriate version, i.e., 32-bit or 64 bit.

**N.B.** The latest fully-tested *release* version is 19.00; v. 21.02 is labeled *alpha*, a test version. So if v. 21.02 is problematic on your PC. use v. 19.00.

Comment: Reinstalling doesn't help, it is seems to be some minor ui option or error. Maybe something with my system if nobody else had this.

Comment: Do you have multiple keyboard languages installed? After switching languages, I found it impossible to log into Windows. Check that simple things like cap locks and language are not causing the issue.

Comment: Somehow it starts working, it can be that reinstalling helped but only after restarting pc. Though I tried reinstalling before, so may be a new version.